# Function promise not returning anything after changed to async

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, paypal, promise

I'm using paypal-node-SDK library to make calls to Paypal API. It uses a promise like this:

```
paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("Create Payment Response");
        console.log(payment);
    }
});
```

However I'm trying to make it `async` because my other functions are `async/await` as well. But it doesn't return any callback, just undefined.

```
        exports.create = wrap(async(req, res) => {
            const payment = await paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json);
        });
        //wrap
        module.exports = (fn) => {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    res.status(400).send({success: false, message: error.message});
                });
            };
        };
```

It seems the library supports promises (feature: [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/pull/287https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/pull/287)), but the `cb(null, response)` doesn't really return anything when it is a async function. Am I missing something? Is there a way to make it work async?

Comment: Only the beta has promise support, are you using beta (2.0+)?

Comment: @CodyG. 1.8.1 version... I'm gonna change to 2.0.0 beta to see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need beta / version 2.0+ to use promises in the sdk.

Not sure exactly what your wrap is, but for node styled callbacks `function foo(a,b,callback)` you can use `promisify`

```
    const { promisify } = require('util');
    exports.create = promisify(paypal.payment.create);
```

A manual conversion of  `paypal.payment.create` would be

```
function create(create_payment_json){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json,function(error,payment){
      if(error){
       reject(error);
      }else{
       resolve(payment);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Which can then be used by `const payment = await create(json);`

Then in your router you can use something like

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  try{
    const payment = await create(json);
    res.send(payment);
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Extending on the answer by Cody G..**

It is correct you need to upgrade to the beta v2+ to use promises in the sdk, although if you wish to do so, after you've upgraded you will find there are breaking changes.

You can read the full documentation here:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/tree/2.0-beta

There is also a migration guide to easily transition from v1 to v2:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/2.0-beta/docs/Migrating.md